# Map enumeration JSON value to readonly static field

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

I have the following typescript type:

```
export class Status {
  static readonly DONE = new Status('DONE', 'p-tag-green');
  static readonly PENDING = new Status('PENDING', 'p-tag-yellow');

  private constructor(
    private _value: string,
    private _class: string
  ) { }
}
```

and it is used in

```
export interface Reminder {
  id: string;
  status: Status;
}
```

When I make my `httpClient` request the JSON `{"id": 5, "status": "DONE"}` is returned, so the `status` field of the parsed `Reminder` object has the string value of `DONE` but it is not actually an object of type `Status`, thus I cannot retrieve the `value` property of the `Status` object.

I can get a `Status` object, if I manually map the response like so:

```
return this.httpClient.get(`api/v1/reminders/${id}`).pipe(
  map((data: any) => ({
    ...data,
    status: Reminder.Status[data['status'] as keyof typeof Reminder.Status]
  }))
);
```

However, since I have a lot of cases like this one, **is it somehow possible, to make this more generic**, so that any interface like `Reminder` which includes any such pseudo-enum type like `Status`? I was thinking about http client interceptors or decorators, but couldn't make any of them work.

- Decorators because I'd need to make the `interface` a `class` which implies more changes I don't like
- Http client interceptor because I don't have the types of the interface/classes that I need to parse to. However, maybe there is some clever prototype inspection that can be done?

Comment: is your real intention to turn a string ("DONE" | "PENDING") into a class and add extra information like 'p-tag-green' or 'p-tag-yellow' as you shown in the example?

Comment: Yes. My business domain has an enumeration - `DONE|PENDING`, and I'd like to associate these values with extra information in a compile-time check. Thus, anytime a new status is added, the compiler forces me to choose tag color.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion this code is over-engineered you don't need to create a static Class to istanciate one single time the status Object, this approach can lead to problems when you try to update Status from another place becouse the reference is only one.
You can follow the immutable way, in your case, create a `new Status` each time you recive a response.

```
export type StatusType = 'DONE' | 'PENDING';

export interface IReminder {
  id: string;
  status: StatusType;
}

// think about this object like a configuration file, something that can be centralized
export const STATUS_STYLES = { 
   DONE: 'p-tag-green', // or a structurated object
   PENDING: 'p-tag-yellow'
}

export class Status {
   value: string;
   style: string;

   constructor(status: StatusType){
       this.value = status;
       this.style = STATUS_STYLES[status];
   }
}

export class Reminder {
  id: string;
  status: Status;

  constructor(reminder: IReminder) {
     this.id = reminder.id;
     this.status = new Status(status)
  }
}

return this.httpClient.get(`api/v1/reminders/${id}`).pipe(
  map((reminder: Reminder) => new Reminder(reminder)))
);
```

you can organize this code into different files, i usually use a file for interfaces and classes called `.model.ts` a file for types and a file or a json for configurations.
This approach keep code simple to read and to extend, removing from map operator business logics.